# How can I make so the DrawerToggle menu field overlay the contents - Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

I wonder if it's possible in Vaadin 14 to make so the DrawerToggle menu field only overlay the content in the class `AppLayout`, instead of pushing the content to the right when I press the DrawerToggle.

https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-app-layout

```
public class AppLayoutWithDrawerMenu extends AppLayout {
    public AppLayoutWithDrawerMenu() {
        Image img = new Image("https://i.imgur.com/GPpnszs.png", "Vaadin Logo");
        img.setHeight("44px");
        addToNavbar(new DrawerToggle(), img);
        Tabs tabs = new Tabs(new Tab("Home"), new Tab("About"));
        tabs.setOrientation(Tabs.Orientation.VERTICAL);
        addToDrawer(tabs);
    }
}
```

When I press the `DrawerToggle`, then the whole content moves to the right. I won't want that. I want the menu of the drawerToggle overlay the content. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force the drawer to always use the “overlay” mode by setting the `--vaadin-app-layout-drawer-overlay` CSS property.

```css
vaadin-app-layout {
  --vaadin-app-layout-drawer-overlay: true;
}
```

See https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17969415/18048801 for the full discussion.

Comment: Thank you! I have read your answer and I will test it and give you a reply later. Brb.